# How can I make my query set order by descending in django based on auto increment id field

Tags: mysql, django

Django Model

```
class logdetail(models.Model):
    scantype = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scanrange = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scandate = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Views.py

```
logDBObj = logdetail.objects.all().filter(id=logdetail_id).order_by('-logdetail_id')
```

I have to collect all the records in logdetail table by descending order of autoincrement id.

I could not find where I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your model but by the looks of it you just need to remove the `logdetail` in your `order_by`:

```
logdetail.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

Comment: also, .all().filter(..) is kinda redundant - if you're filtering, you don't need .all()

Comment: aand, the way you filter by one id, you should only ever get one object back

Comment: I have to collect all the records from logdetail by descending order of Auto increment id

Comment: Then as @martin said, your query will filter out all but one record. Simply use `objects.all()` to get all the `logdetail` records

Comment: Then the query would be like this.
logdetail.objects.all().order_by('-id')
this is giving all the records for me but in ascending order of id

Comment: Have you read [any of the documentation at all](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)? Take out the `-`